# Google Fit Api filter manually added activities

Tags: java, android, rest, google-fit

[Google Fit](https://fit.google.com/) allows users to add activities manually and programatically. Is it possible to filter out manually or programtically added activities from either the Android Api or the REST Api?

I want to query for only activities that were actually tracked and recorded at the time they were performed.

Comment: I am looking for the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496847/not-cheatable-google-fit-step-counter

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is reading the steps in real time so you know that the steps are real and have not been entered manually. Is there a way I can contact you? We could ask Google if they are considering adding what de need to their API. You can send me a DM on Twitter @sammleach

Answer (score 2):

There is no proper way according to the documentation. But I found some solution to identify manual and automatic tracked activities in Android API.

```
DataSource ds = DataPoint.getOriginalDataSource()
String streamData = ds.getStreamIdentifier()
```

If "streamData"  contains "user_input", then it assumes the activities to be manual activities, either it contains "detailed" for actual sensor recorded activities.

Comment: Have tried DataPoint.getOriginalDataSource().getAppPackageName() and it returns 'null'. Have also tried DataPoint.getOriginalDataSource().getStreamIdentifier() and it has some value which is not readable.

Comment: Should be marked as answer. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I tried as suggested by Abdul Khan above but

```java
DataSource ds = DataPoint.getOriginalDataSource();
String streamData = ds.getStreamIdentifier();

/*I also tried but could not achieve what I wanted*/

String packageName = ds.getAppPackageName();
String streamIdentifier = ds.getStreamIdentifier();
```

did not work at least for me while retrieving data. I ended up using **readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice()** as shown below in order to capture steps captured by device only.

```java
Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice(mApiClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

I cross checked the same with some of the apps that avoids manual entries in their app and the count provided by the function above is exactly the same.

**Note:** If a user is having multiple devices and is using the app on all of them, **readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice()** will have different value for each and every device since the function is responsible for returning device specific data only.